# How to study Rosen book in discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation, advice

I am student in computer science and want to build a strong background in mathematics.  A teacher recommended Rosen's book but now I don't now how to study it with myself.  Do you have advice, recommendations or pointers to online resources?

Shall I study it from beginning to end?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! For a strong background in math, you will want to focus most heavily on sets, induction, number theory, and counting. Read through and make sure you understand the proofs, then do the exercises to make sure you can come up with your own.

Comment: Every thing that you know about computers will mislead you when attempting to learn math,   So when you are studying math, forget all that computer stuff.  It has been observed that computer students are the hardest  students to teach math to,  Find math books that do not try to explain math as though it was computer programming,